# Trying to perform Linear search in java using functions

Tags: java, function

I'm trying to use a void method to input an array and call it in the main function. Its just performing simple linear search. Is there any way I can let the linear return function access the array arr or would I just have to put the input method under the main function.
On VC Code this is the error "The method linear(int, int[], int) in the type prg is not applicable for the arguments (int, Class<arr[]>, int)Java(67108979)"

```
import java.util.*;
class prg{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int len,num,arr[],x;
    void input(){
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
        int len = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[len];
        System.out.println("Enter the Array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number to look for: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
       }
    int linear (int len, int arr[], int num){
        for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++){
            if(arr[i] == num){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
        }
    void main(){
        prg obj = new prg();
        obj.input();
        x = obj.linear (len,arr[],num);
        if(x >= 0){
            System.out.println("The number " + num + " is found at the index: " + x);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The number " + num + " was not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Just trying to make the input function separate from main.
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a proper main declaration: `void main(){` so I suspect what is going on is VC is running some other code and trying to smoosh it into your code, and it's not working.  Show us the actual `main` code, or make this one correct, and then make sure you are running the right file / project.

Comment: `arr[]` in `x = obj.linear (len,arr[],num);` is not valid || @markspace or OP is using the preview feature [JEP 445](https://openjdk.org/jeps/445) allowing `void main()` as main method

Comment: further more `int arr[] = new int[len];` is creating and initializing a new local variable, not setting the instance variable.

Comment: @user16320675 Does that work here?  `void main()` is inside a class definition, I thought it should be only valid outside of a class.

Comment: @markspace it does work - tested (but got slightly different error: missing `.class` at call to `linear`) and described in JEP445: "*When launching a class, the launch protocol chooses the first of the following methods to invoke: . . . 4. A void main() instance method of non-private access declared in the launched class or inherited from a superclass*", including [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1khp5.png) in its [Description](https://openjdk.org/jeps/445#Description) section

Comment: That's going to make debugging newbie programs rather more problematic.  I'm not sure I like that JEP any more. @user16320675

Comment: @markspace After reading about it I don't like it.  Imho, by "reducing clutter" on simple programs that JEP is cluttering up the language.   All students need to understand is that you need to do a, b, and c, to get their program running.  And then latter they can learn how a, b, and c work and what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Is there any way I can let the linear return function access the array arr or would I just have to put the input method under the main function. ..."*

This is possible; your syntax is incorrect, is all.

Firstly, from your *input* method, you'll want to remove the declaration types for the variables, *len*, *arr*, and *num*.
This will allow you to access the *class variables*, with the same names.
Otherwise, you are simply declaring new local variables, for the *input* method's scope.

Additionally, remove the brackets, `[]`, from the *arr* variable within *input*—these are only required during the declaration.

```java
len = sc.nextInt();
arr = new int[len];
num = sc.nextInt();
```

> *"... On VC Code this is the error 'The method linear(int, int[], int) in the type prg is not applicable for the arguments (int, Class<arr[]>, int)Java(67108979)' ..."*

Similar to above, this is because the *arr* variable is affixed the brackets, `[]`.  Just use the name *arr*.

```java
x = obj.linear (len,arr,num);
```

Furthermore, the *main* method signature in *Java* is the following.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

You'll need that method declaration signature, for the compiler to locate a starting point—just, *void main()*, will not suffice.

From here you'll need to access the *prg* variables using dot-notation.

```java
obj.x = obj.linear (obj.len,obj.arr,obj.num);
```

And on a final note, the *for-loop* conditional statements, of both *input* and *linear* are using *i <= len*.  You'll want to change this to *i < len*, since when *i* starts at *0*, there would be 1 additional iteration.

Here is the complete code, for reference.

```java
public class prg {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int len,num,arr[],x;
    void input(){
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
        len = sc.nextInt();
        arr = new int[len];
        System.out.println("Enter the Array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number to look for: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
    }
    int linear (int len, int arr[], int num){
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if(arr[i] == num){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prg obj = new prg();
        obj.input();
        obj.x = obj.linear (obj.len,obj.arr,obj.num);
        if(obj.x >= 0){
            System.out.println("The number " + obj.num + " is found at the index: " + obj.x);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The number " + obj.num + " was not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AnyReader - note that "*the main method signature in Java is the following. `public static void main(String[] args) { }` You'll need that method declaration signature, for the compiler to locate a starting point—just, void main(), will not suffice.*" is not correct for Java 21 with preview features enabled- see [JEP 445](https://openjdk.org/jeps/445) -  (and posted code is not (just) a signature)

Answer (score -1):

You can't create a new array just by `arr[]`, it doesn't have a type.

`input()` should return the array like

```
int[] input(){
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
        int len = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[len];
        System.out.println("Enter the Array: ");
        for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number to look for: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        return arr;
}
```

And then

```
x = obj.linear (len,obj.input(),num);
```